# Finding position of each word in a sub-array of a multidimensional array

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have an array:

```
tokens = [["hello","world"],["hello","ruby"]]
all_tokens = tokens.flatten.uniq # all_tokens=["hello","world","ruby"]
```

Now I need to create two arrays corresponding to all_tokens, where the first array will contain the position of each word in sub-array of tokens. I.E Output:

```
[[0,0],[1],[1]] # (w.r.t all_tokens)
```

To make it clear it reads, The index of "hello" is 0 and 0 in the 2 sub-arrays of tokens.

And second array contains index of each word w.r.t tokens.I.E Output:

```
[[0,1],[0],[1]]
```

To make it clear it reads,the index of hello 0,1. I.E "hello" is in index 0 and 1 of tokens array.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach sounds difficult to maintain. If you stay on your current path, you'll end up with your `tokens` array-of-arrays, an array of unique tokens (`all_tokens`), and then two additional array-of-arrays to keep track of the positions of the unique tokens within the original `tokens` structure.

An alternative approach is to start with the most natural way to store the unique tokens: **a hash**. Within that hash you can also store the positional information. That way, all of the information travels together.

There might be a slicker way to achieve this, but here's a simple implementation:

```
tokens = [["hello","world"],["hello","ruby"]]

token_info     = {}
ordered_tokens = []

tokens.each_with_index do |group, i|
    group.each_with_index do |t, j|
        unless token_info.has_key?(t)
            token_info[t] = {:i => [], :j => []}
            ordered_tokens.push(t)
        end
        token_info[t][:i].push(i)
        token_info[t][:j].push(j)
    end
end

ordered_tokens.each do |t|
    p t, token_info[t]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with FM, but this will create your first array:

```
tokens = [["hello","world"],["hello","ruby"]]
all_tokens = tokens.flatten.uniq

sublist_indices = all_tokens.collect do |token|
  tokens.inject([]) do |indices, list|
    indices += list.each_with_index.select {|pair| pair[0] == token}.map {|pair| pair[1]}
  end
end  # => [[0, 0], [1], [1]]
```

Remainder left as an exercise.